# Regex: How to grab all characters until reaching another two characters?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have a string such as this...

```
"test_test_test":"Hello \"Hello\" Hello","Oh_yea_oh_yea","Hi there buddy"
```

I want to grab

```
"test_test_test":"Hello \"Hello\" Hello"
```

So far my regex is this...

```
"test_test_test":
```

This would grab the key and colon. I will always know what `"test_test_test"` is, I just won't know what the value is after the colon. It would be easy if I knew there wouldn't be escaped quotations inside the quotations themselves, but there are. Thanks!

EDIT:

There can be commas inside, and there cannot be a quotation that's not escaped inside.

My idea is something along the lines of...

```
"test_test_test":"[^(",)]*
```

In my head, this says keep going until you find the single quotation followed by a comma,  (",) then stop. However that doesn't work above.

Comment: Can you have escaped backslash as well?  e.g. \\

Comment: No, there cannot be escaped backslashes.

Comment: Can there be a comma in the quoted string?

Comment: yes there can be. I think the best way is what I provided above in my edit, to keep looking until there's a quotation and then a comma, because every quotation inside the value will always be escaped.

Comment: No, that wouldn't work either because there can be.. \",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the RAW regex. You may need to add more escape if you put into string or include a separator.

```
"test_test_test":"(?:[^"\\]|\\[\\"])*"
```

If you need flexible spacing:

```
"test_test_test" *: *"(?:[^"\\]|\\[\\"])*"
```

The key part is here: `(?:[^"\\]|\\[\\"])*`. It will match 0 or more of: non-quote-or-backslash, or escaped quote `\"` or escaped backslash `\\`.

The regex above is still imprecise: the content in the quoted string is allowed to span multiple lines. Whether it is good or not depends on the grammar for the quoted string. However, multi-line quoted string in the languages I have seen usually doesn't take the form described in my regex.

The regex also treats the quoted string `"\n"` as invalid. You can easily modify the regex a bit to accommodate those cases, though.

Comment: hahaha!! you're awesome... would it be too difficult to explain the meaning of that?

Comment: FWIW, `|\\[\\"]` doesn't appear to be necessary, and `*: *` could be shortened to `.*?`.

Comment: @rockerest: I prefer strict regex. And `\\[\\"]` is important to allow escaped quote and escaped ``\``.

Comment: @unwiseguy: I was writing an explanation. And the caveats are also included.

Comment: It still matches escaped quotes and escaped `\ ` without `\\[\\"]`... What engine are you using to test this expression?

Comment: @rockerest: It is RAW regex. If the regex is quoted in string, you need to escape ``\``, and ``"`` may also need to be escaped. If you need testing: http://www.regex101.com/r/eP3pA3 or go to regexplanet

Comment: What is the purpose of the question mark? I read that question is used  to make capturing preceding characters optional. But this doesn't look like it's doing that.

Comment: @unwiseguy: `(?:pattern)` is non-capturing group. Normally `(pattern)` is capturing - but we don't need it. `?` also means optional, but not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to select the key and the first entry before the comma.

### Update:

You actually want the first quoted string regardless of its contents.

So your regex might look like this: `/"test_test_test".*?"(?:[^"\\])*"/`

## Update 2:

This regex doesn't choke on escapes inside the string: `"test_test_test".*?".*[^\\"].*?"(?=,)`

Comment: This is so not going to work. The regex will be greedy and eat everything up to the last `,`

Comment: It actually does work, I just tested it.  Unless the specifications are different than I assumed, it's successful.

Comment: It will match up to "Oh_yea_oh_yea". Comma in the quoted string will also mess up your match.

Comment: After the question was updated to include multiple commas, I've updated the regex to stop after one.

Comment: Comma in quoted string will mess up your match. e.g. `"test_test_test":"comma,here","more"`

Comment: Yup, he updated the question again.  I guess I'll fix it and update anyway.